# I simply can not install Virtual Box properly and start VM in it

Tags: kernel, kali-linux, virtualbox

I have an issue with the result of not being able to start a virtual machine.

> well known Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

I have tried

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
linux-headers-4.9.0-kali4-amd64 is already the newest version (4.9.25-1kali1)
```

During vbox installation I am reading this error messages:

```
Building for 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 4.9.0-kali4-amd64 Module build for kernel 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 was skipped since the kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated; vendor preset: enabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-06-01 00:04:55 UTC; 4ms ago Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8) Process: 5650 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 01 00:04:55 kali systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module... 
Jun 01 00:04:55 kali virtualbox[5650]: Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...…led! 
Jun 01 00:04:55 kali virtualbox[5650]: failed! Jun 01 00:04:55 kali systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited…us=1 
Jun 01 00:04:55 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kern…ule. 
Jun 01 00:04:55 kali systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state. 
Jun 01 00:04:55 kali systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'ex…de'.
```

based on the output I suppose to install older headers?

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to missing Virtual Box kernel modules (drivers). Try this:

```
apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
dkms add -m virtualbox -v 4.3.36 # or whatever the version of virtualbox-dkms you install.
```

That should install the Virtual Box kernel module source code, and then use Debian's DKMS to compile the modules with your current kernel.

Of course, given that you'd be messing with the kernel, which is a critical point of the OS, you may want to [read](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelDKMS) up on DKMS first.